# Django - cannot get loaddata to work

Tags: sql, json, django, default

I have been using a Django database for a while without any major issues. Today I needed to set default values for a few tables for the first time. I created a fixtures directory in the top-level Django directory. Then I created the files for the default values. However, I keep getting error messages and I'm not sure why.

First I tried to use .sql files. It is worth noting that these tables are very simple; they only have one value, "name". My SQL file looked like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (name) VALUES ('Default');
```

I saved this as `MyTable.sql`. When I ran the command `python manage.py loaddata fixtures/MyTable.sql`, I got this error message:

```
CommandError: Problem installing fixture 'MyTable': sql is not a known serialization format.
```

(Note: I also tried without the fixtures/ part, for the above example and the next, and got identical results).

I asked my project lead and he said he doesn't think SQL files can be used for this. So, I tried JSON files. My `MyTable.json` looked like this:

`[
    {
        "model": "mydatabase.MyTable",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "name": "Default"
        }
    }
]`

I'll be very upfront to admit I've never worked with JSON in this context before, only in web development, so I don't know if the issue may be something I'm doing wrong here. I tried to base it on the formatting I found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/). When I ran this through the loaddata function again, I got this error message:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py:216: UserWarning: No fixture named 'fixtures/MyTable' found.
```

This is my first time doing this and I've had a bit of a hard time finding documentation to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Could anyone please offer advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create your fixture files start with an empty database and then add some data to your database using the djanog-admin or the django shell or even pure SQL. After that you can do a

```
python manage.py dumpdata # to dump all your data, or 
python manage.py dumpdata app_name # to dump all data of a specific app, or 
python manage.py dumpdata app_name.model_name # to dump all data of a specific model
```

The above will print data to your stdout. In order to write it to a file use a redirect (>), for instance

```
python manage.py dumpdata auth.User > user_fixture.json
```

*Update:* I just saw that you are using Windows -- remember to load your fixtures using a backslash (`\`).

Comment: After I drop and recreate the database to start with it empty, would I need to run syncdb or any migrations to recreate the tables that the sql files refer to?

Comment: You don't need to drop an recrate the database. Just do a dumpdata right now (if it contains data of course).

Comment: I just ran all three of the above commands, each time it returned `[]`, but when I tried the loaddata again after it gave the same error :(

Comment: Try adding some data to your database then (and do a syncdb and a migrate) first and then try running ``python manage.py dumpdata`` to check that something is outputted.

Comment: When I added a value manually through the program we're working on with these databases and ran it it shows up

Comment: I just saw your edit above about the backslashes, when I changed that it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

As for me, the matter is the suffix of the output file.

```
python manage.py dumpdata -o my_dump
python manage.py loaddata < my_dump # it fails
# change the file name my_dump to my_dump.json
python manage.py loaddata < my_dump.json  # it works
```

---

So, I guess the `dumpdata` implicitly use `json` as output format. While `loaddata` needs a format tip from file name suffix.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this like below

## models.py

```
from django import models

class Model_Name(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## fixures

```
[
  {
    "model": "app_name.model_name",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
        "name": "My app name"
    }
  }
]
```

## command

```
./manage.py loaddata app_name/fixtures/model_name.json
```

## Output: Installed 1 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)

Answer (score 1):

For those who still having this issues.

The error is telling you that:

> CommandError: Problem installing fixture 'MyTable': sql is not a known serialization format.

You could look on it as:

> **sql** is not a known serialization format.

It will not accept any file not ending on `.json`.

So to solve your problem use this command:

```
$ python manage.py loaddata <your_dump_filename>.json
```